# Android + Eclipse 4.1

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed the android plugin for eclipse, on eclipse 4.1. Everything works except the DDMS perspective.
Any of you guys know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in 4.2

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19105

Answer (score 4):

You should use Eclipse 3.7. Eclipse 4.* is a work in progress and shouldn't be used in production environments yet.

Comment: According to the Eclipse FAQ, Eclipse 4.1 is a full mature version. You can check here. http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/Eclipse_SDK_4.0_FAQ#Eclipse_SDK_4.1_Release

Comment: @Stew That would be referring to the SDK, not the actually dev environment. Indigo (3.7) was just released today.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with Chris that 3.7 is the stable environment to use, there's not really anything wrong with using an unstable development environment if you're willing to accept the risks that go along with it (generally I would think that issues would mostly be limited to design-time and not run-time). If the only thing that is missing is the DDMS perspective, you could consider simply running DDMS directly instead of inside Eclipse.